# how to auto focus an .Net winform application running in background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a weird problem, my .net win form application triggers a third party CRM application. When the customer is working with CRM application and clicks some button in my application, on first click the button does not trigger the event, only on the second click it responds.

The reason I suspect is that my application is not in focus.

I tried with the following code

```
private void XXXXX_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BringToFront();
        this.Focus();
    }
```

But then its not working. I am new to .Net can any one point me how to fix this issue?

Any help is highly appreciated.

update:  my toolstrip button.

```
btnbutton.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //some code to execute on button click.

        };
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't really get the relation between your form and CRM application UI, I think a screen shot would help.

Comment: @King King, there is no relation to CRM as such, apart from triggering the CRM URL. I have updated my question.

Comment: so what is the main UI? your form or any other?

Comment: @@King King. My UI will be on the top of the screen and the CRM would be launched below.

Comment: At the time you click on your button, do you see if your form caption looks like inactivated?

Comment: if your form is on top, I think your problem is so strange, check out your button click event handler instead.

Comment: The .NET tool strip ignores clicks when the application doesn't have focus. If this is the problem you're having, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickbrew/archive/2006/01/09/511003.aspx for a solution.

Comment: @KingKing I have updated with button event handler code. I could not find any issues in that. When I click in a empty space in the plane and then click the button it works fine on the first click.

Comment: @Pieter I suspect that might be the problem. Thanks for the link I ll look into that.

Comment: @ArunKumar maybe the solution at the Pieter's link will help you, you didn't say your button is a toolstripbutton.

Comment: @KingKing thanks. I apologies for that. Before I could update my question. I saw pieters answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET tool strip ignores clicks when the application doesn't have focus. This is just like how Words work. The idea here is that the user can click "anywhere" in the window without having to worry that he actually performs an action. Only when the window has focus will the click "count".

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickbrew/archive/2006/01/09/511003.aspx describes how you can work around this. Basically, you inherit from `ToolStrip` and override the `WndProc`, and change the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` with the `MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT` result to the `MA_ACTIVATE` result.

Comment: Is this the issue only in .net V2 or in all .Net framework versions.

Comment: Definitely do this *instead* of setting the focus on mouse-over. Or if you prefer to set the focus on mouse-over, use [the system setting for that](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/switch-windows-by-hovering-the-mouse-over-a-window-in-windows-vista/) instead of implementing it only for a single application—too confusing.

Comment: @CodyGray This solution worked in my lab. I will test this in client place today.

Comment: @CodyGray Unfortunately, my client is using windows XP. Is there any way to configure a similar option in windows XP?

Comment: @Arun Like the article I linked says, "In the old days, this used to be called the XWindows mode, and was enabled through TweakUI, but now it’s built right into Control Panel for everybody to use.". You can download TweakUI for Windows XP [here from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/xp-downloads#2TC=featured). Totally safe, it's just enabling a feature that there is otherwise no way to configure. But just for the record, I think it's a confusing setting and you should be really careful about enabling it *globally* across the entire system just to fix one app's behavior.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. I will use the tool on a trial basis. If we are not comfortable, I will remove the settings.